# Mongodb unable to start shell in MacOs

Tags: mongodb, macos, php-7.2, macos-catalina

I am trying to start mongodb shell on macOS Catalina.

I can't use /data/db path because Catalina has a surprise change: it won't allow changes to the root directory.

```
% sudo mkdir -p /data/db
mkdir: /data/db: Read-only file system
```

then created this path

```
/Users/username/data/db
```

and used below command

```
mongod --dbpath ~/data/db
```

but still I am getting same issue.

Installed mongodb using

```
 sudo pecl install mongodb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of Catalina has a surprise change and it won't allow changes to the root directory.
I created this folder in

`/Users/your-user-name/data/db`

run `whoami` on terminal you will get your username.

and then

1) Start terminal use

```
mongod --dbpath Users/your-user-name/data/db
```

and

2) Open another tab of your terminal and run

```
mongo
```

Now, I can access mongo shell.